# 'I'm kind of slammed' mean?

Tags: spoken-english

I heard the sentence in a movie:

> I'm kind of slammed.

My guess is that I'm kind of overwhelmed by lots of work. But I am not quite sure. What does it truly mean? Under what circumstances would it possibly be used?

Comment: It's not an expression that I have heard used, but the Urban Dictionary defines it like this: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=slammed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/slammed) it's derived from Swedish:

- [slamra](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/swedish-english/slamra) {vb}
  EN: to clatter, to pound, to pound away, to pound out.

Without knowing which movie you refer to it likely means drunk or busy (a lot on my plate, a lot on my mind).